# Edit magento database through module

Tags: php, sql, magento

I'm fairly new to magento so I'm sorry if it seems easy to you.
I'm using webkul marketplace for this site.
I have two groups of clients: `retailer` and `display`, I'm trying to make it so that if a client is `display` all of its products will have an attribute set on `only display`, otherwise the attribute will be set on `sellable`.
 I'm running my function in the `IndexController.php` of my module but I couldn't manage to call my products from the database.

The product's attribute is called `category` and I created it as a system attribute while the client's one is called `group_id` in `costumer_entity` table.

Comment: Hi for any kind of issues if you are getting you can contact to the support as well https://webkul.com/contacts/

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the products from your catalogue you have to access them via their model.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

On top of that you could add filters to the collection with something like:

```
$products ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

And if it happens you have the store_id available, you can add the store id filter to the collection like this

```
$products ->addStoreFilter($store_id);
```

I hope I could have been helpful

F